# Ionic run app in browser with different devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

How do I run my ionic application within the browser where I can select the 3 **different devices**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the following command in commandline or terminal from within your project folder:

```
ionic serve -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a local dev server for app dev/testing

> Project folder > run cmd

then put and run

```
ionic serve
```

after you can see your

Development server running!

Local: http://localhost:8100

External: http://192.168.1.xx:8100

DevApp: example@8100 on DESKTOP-pc

you can run it any devises using following address
 External: `http://192.168.1.xx:8100`

[image: cmd image here]